# count the devices that has the same firmware

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Just want to count the number of devices and display it here:
[image: Image Example]

I have tried using
`"SELECT DISTINCT Firmware, COUNT(SerialNumber) FROM SoftwareCycle GROUP BY Model"`

however, the firmware gets duplicated.
[image: Image Example]

here is the table structure:
[image: Image Example]

Comment: Kindly read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and modify your question and **Images should only be used to illustrate problems that can't be made clear in any other way, such as to provide screenshots of a user interface.** Please check **[Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)**

Comment: From what I can see is because you are counting your serial number. 
also using Distinct will not help you in your current problem. 
"SELECT Firmware, COUNT(Firmware) FROM SoftwareCycle GROUP BY Model"

I am not sure how much this is going to help you but give it a try, the above should give you  Firmware - and then howmany devices use this Firmware 

How ever if you have   Windows 10.1  32 devices 
and then you have       Windows 10.2 10 devices 
then it will not count it as   42 devices for windows 10. but as 2 different records

let me know if the above code helped at all